# Cluster Marker not hiding when zoom in

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2, markerclusterer

I'm trying to implement a cluster marker on my map, and it is behaving a little strange, first, it shows me the cluster marker but also shows me the point markers, that shouldn't be happening, and when I zoom in the cluster marker still showing, i'll add some images to explain it better.

[image]

[image]

```
public class MapaViagem extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private String rm_IdViagem;
    private List<ClienteModel> mClienteModel = new ArrayList<ClienteModel>();
    private List<EnderecoModel> mEnderecoModel = new ArrayList<EnderecoModel>();
    private ViagemModel mViagemModel = new ViagemModel();
    private ClusterManager<MyItem> mClusterManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.maps);
         ArrayList<LatLng> coordList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        try {

            Bundle parametros = getIntent().getExtras();
            rm_IdViagem = parametros.getString("id_viagem");

            Repositorio ca = new Repositorio(this);
            mViagemModel = ca.getViagemPorId(Integer.valueOf(rm_IdViagem));

            Repositorio cl = new Repositorio(this);
            mClienteModel = cl.getClientesViagem(Integer.valueOf(rm_IdViagem));


            System.out.println("TEM CLIENTE " + mClienteModel.size());

            if(mClienteModel != null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < mClienteModel.size(); i++) {


                    Repositorio mRepositorio = new Repositorio(this);
                    mEnderecoModel = mRepositorio.getListaEnderecosDoCliente(Integer.valueOf(mClienteModel.get(i).getClientes_id()));


                    for (int j = 0; j < mEnderecoModel.size(); j++) {
                        // Loading map
                        initilizeMap();
                        // Changing map type
                        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

                        // Showing / hiding your current location
                        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                        // Enable / Disable zooming controls
                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

                        // Enable / Disable my location button
                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

                        // Enable / Disable Compass icon
                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

                        // Enable / Disable Rotate gesture
                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

                        // Enable / Disable zooming functionality
                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);


                        final float latitude = Float.parseFloat(mEnderecoModel.get(j).getLatitude());
                        final float longitude = Float.parseFloat(mEnderecoModel.get(j).getLongitude());


                        coordList.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));


                        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 10));



                        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(MapaViagem.this, googleMap);


                        mClusterManager.setRenderer(new MyClusterRenderer(MapaViagem.this, googleMap, mClusterManager));

                        googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
                        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);


                        addItems(coordList);

                    }


                }
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public class MyClusterRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MyItem> {

        public MyClusterRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map,
                                 ClusterManager<MyItem> clusterManager) {
            super(context, map, clusterManager);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyItem item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
            super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);



//            item.setTitle(mClienteModel.get(i));
            markerOptions.title(item.getTitle());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onClusterItemRendered(MyItem clusterItem, Marker marker) {
            super.onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem, marker);

            //here you have access to the marker itself
        }

 @Override
        protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster<MyItem> cluster) {
            return cluster.getSize() > 3; // when count of markers is more than 3, render as cluster
        }
    }


    private void addItems(List<LatLng> markers) {

        for (int i = 0; i < markers.size(); i++) {
            MyItem offsetItem = new MyItem(markers.get(i));
            mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);

        }
        mClusterManager.cluster();
    }



    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Não foi possível carregar o mapa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }


}
```

Model:

```
public class MyItem implements ClusterItem {

    private LatLng mPosition;
    private String title;

    public MyItem(LatLng position){
        mPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public LatLng getPosition() {
        return mPosition;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Comment: ..have you found a way to do this, even i'm facing the same problem , when the markers are in the same location. Would like to know how you got it done.

Comment: @AshwinNarayanan I just stop using cluster markers, I couldn`t solve that, sorry

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you need to define, when your `ClusterManager` should clusterize, so there is a method in `MyClusterRenderer` you should override:

```
@Override
protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster<MyItem> cluster) {
    return cluster.getSize() > 3; // when count of markers is more than 3, render as cluster
}
```

Secondly, when you make some changes with your markers such as adding, removing, changing title, icon, location, you should call `cluster()` method. So your `addItems` method should look like this:

```
private void addItems(List<LatLng> markers) {

    for (int i = 0; i < markers.size(); i++) {
        MyItem offsetItem = new MyItem(markers.get(i));
        mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
    }
    mClusterManager.cluster();
}
```

**EDIT:**

I just look at your code one more time, and found that you forgot to set the clusterizing algorithm, it should be:

```
    ...
    mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(MapaViagem.this, googleMap);
    mClusterManager.setAlgorithm(new GridBasedAlgorithm<MyItem>());

    mClusterManager.setRenderer(new MyClusterRenderer(MapaViagem.this, googleMap, mClusterManager));
    ...
```

Comment: I did  the changes you suggest but still getting the same results

Comment: now it is even worse, I'm getting a cluster marker with count of 5, and it is not in my LatLng parameters

Comment: I have the same problem. However, the GridBaseAlgorithm place markers on a grid and they are quite far from their real location. It's really annoying although it hides the cluster. Do you know how to fix this ? Maybe with another algorithm

Comment: I had a similar problem i.e. my markers and clusters only come when I zoom in/out for the first time. calling mClusterManager.cluster(); worked for me, thanks a lot dude

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old post, but today I had the same issue.

After spend hour trying to solve, I finally got what happen with my application:
The thing is that the cluster manager is working correctly, the problem is that my method which populates the map was being called twice.

To solve this issue just add `mMap.clear();` before add markers. Works here like a charm!

Bye.

Comment: it what i so long found

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and solved it by making sure that the ClusterManager was only being created and assigned once to the map, try putting and if statement in your create method. 
Most likely when you are initialising the map again in onResume that is causing the issue.

```
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;

    //only create one instance of cluster manager, 
    // if created again in onResume then click listeners don't work on reload and 
    //some markers don't disappear correctly on Zoom
    if (clusterManager == null){
    clusterManager =new ClusterManager(this, map);
     }

    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterManager);
    map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(clusterManager.getMarkerManager());
    map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    //noinspection MissingPermission
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.setOnCameraIdleListener(clusterManager);


    clusterManager.setOnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener(this);


    clusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<MyItem>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onClusterItemClick(MyItem item) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
```