# Android: Google Maps Clustermanager behaves weirdly. The cluster icon does not go away sometimes on full zoom. Why?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2, markermanager

I wrote the following method to display my markers (clustered). However, some of the clusters work fine - i.e. when I zoom in, the blue cluster icon (that says 10+ for ex) goes away and reveals the individual markers. 
However, some times, when I zoom in fully, the blue cluster marker is still displayed on full zoom ALONG with one of the individual markers. Why is this happening?

```
private void displayCluster(List<MyItem> items) {

      mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, googleMap);
      mClusterManager.setRenderer(new MyRender(getApplicationContext(),googleMap,mClusterManager));

      googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
      googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

       for (MyItem item : items) {
           mClusterManager.addItem(item);
       }
   }
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236046/cluster-marker-not-hiding-when-zoom-in. may help you

Comment: I tried the three steps there, and they didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 6):

DefaultClusterRenderer decides whether the markers should be clustered or not.This class contains DefaultClusterRenderer#shouldRenderAsCluster() method - in which the clustering starts only when size of cluster is > MIN_CLUSTER_SIZE. Default value of MIN_CLUSTER_SIZE is 4.

You need to extend DefaultClusterRenderer class and override shouldRenderAsCluster() method to provide your own logic:

```
class CustomRenderer<T extends ClusterItem> extends DefaultClusterRenderer<T>
{
    public CustomRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map, ClusterManager<T> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);            
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster<T> cluster) {
        //start clustering if at least 2 items overlap
        //Change your logic here
        return cluster.getSize() > 1;
    }
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMap != null) {
        return;
    }
    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    if (mMap != null) {
        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<Place>(this, mMap);
        mClusterManager.setRenderer(new CustomRenderer<Place>(this, mMap, mClusterManager));
        ........
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the shouldRenderAsCluster().  Another way also is to set the minimum cluster size, like setMinClusterSize(1);